Creating an image dynamically with PIL and allowing users to download through Flask app [no temp file]
I spent 2 days trying to figure this out and all the tutorials and forums either use temp file or datauri.
The issue with temp file is that its not viable for my hosting solution (Heroku) and datauri is not feasible as image to base64 results in a very long uri (HTTP 414 Error)

For flask route
from flask import request, send_file
import PIL
from io import BytesIO

@app.route('/generate-share-image', methods=['POST'])
def generate_image():
    data = request.get_json()
    img: PIL.Image.Image = generate_img(data)

    img_bytes = BytesIO()
    img.save(img_bytes, format='PNG')
    img_bytes.seek(0)
    return send_file(img_bytes, mimetype='image/png')

For front end button with javascript
<body>
     <button id="shareImageButton" class="btn btn-info align-items-center">
         SHARE GENERATED IMAGE
     </button>
</body>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    // Share Image
    let shareImageButton = document.getElementById("shareImageButton");
    shareImageButton.addEventListener('click', async event => {
          const response = await fetch('/generate-share-image', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify( data : {{ data }}),
          }.then(response => response.blob())
           .then(blob => {
                 const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                 const a = document.createElement('a');
                 a.href = url;
                 a.download = 'qrcode.png';
                 document.body.appendChild(a);
                 a.click();
                 window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
         });
});
</script>

